# How to fix button press in ipywidgets?

Tags: python, jupyter, ipywidgets

I have the following code in a jupyter noteboook with `ipywidgets` 7.5.1 which is a login mask

```
from ipywidgets import widgets

class Login:
    def __init__(self):
        text21 = widgets.Text(description="username")   
        text22 = widgets.Text(description = "password")
        self.button = widgets.Button(
            description='Login NSG',
            disabled=False,
            button_style='info', 
            tooltip='Login with username and password',            
        )        
        self.vbox_conf = widgets.VBox(children=[text21, text22, self.button])             
        self.button.observe(self.login) 
        # alternative: self.button.observe(self.login, names='value') 
        display(self.vbox_conf)            

    def login(self, args):
        print("test")
        print(args)    

login = Login()
```

It renders a login mask, but when I press the button nothing happens! Nothing is printed out, nor in the notebook nor in the Log window!

What is going on and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: You have to use the method `on_click` to handle a button being clicked

```
  self.button.on_click(self.login)
```

This is an **undocumented feature** (or at least very hard to find in the incomplete and misleading [documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html)).

Comment: The documentation for this exact feature is the first item under the Widget Events page.

https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Events.html

Comment: Out of curiousity, which part of the documentation regarding this did you find misleading? If there are improvements that could be made it would be good to hear them.

Comment: But not for the documentation of 'Button': https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#Button

Comment: Fair enough, I imagine reason the docs separate out the basic creation of widgets and the events is that not all widgets support all events. I would not consider the features *undocumented* though.